# JSON Schema format validation not working

Tags: python, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am using strict-rfc3339 as a dependency for my project and trying to validate the json schema date and date-time format. If i pass only date, it is working fine but when i pass as a JSON(Key-value pair) it is not validating.

Below is a sample

```
from jsonschema import validate, FormatChecker       

# throws validation error as expected        
validate( {"2001-02"}, {"type": "string", "format": "date"}, format_checker=FormatChecker()) 

# Doesn't throw error which is wrong
validate({"dob": "2001-02"}, {"dob": {"type": "string", "format": "date"}}, format_checker=FormatChecker())
```

Can someone help ? am i missing something ?

Answer (score 2):

Your second schema is not written correctly. It should be:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "dob": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "date"
    }
  }
}
```

You can read more about specifying nested objects and properties at https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html.